# Как сделать поиск по txt файлу1 используя строки из файла 2

Tags: php, массивы, строки, список, скрипт

возникла такая задача:

есть 2 файла `domen.txt` c доменами

```
domen.txt
domen.ru
domen.com
domen.net
domen.org
```

и `url.txt` с сылками в которых встречаются эти домены

```
http://domen.ru/wp-logon.php
http://domen1.ru/contact/login/int.php
http://www.domen.com/my-dir/user.php
https://www.domen.net/my-dir/admin.php
```

Нужно взять строку из файла domen.txt(domen.ru) проверить наличие ссылки с этим доменом в файле url.txt, если ссылка есть записать её в файл good.txt если ссылки с названием домена(domen.org) нет, записать домен в no-url.txt Если не сложно напишите пожалуйста пример кода с комментариями что за что отвечает,что бы чайнику можно было разобраться.
код который пока получилось написать:

```
 <?php $fp0 = fopen( "good.txt", "a+" );// для добавления в конец 
          $fp1 = fopen( "no-url.txt", "a+" );
    $file_array = file("domens.txt");//Считывание файла в массив $file_array
    // Работа с данными массива
    foreach($file_array as $age)
    if (strpos(file_get_contents("url.txt"), "{$age}")){

        echo "<br>Искомая строка найдена";


        }else{
        echo "<br>Искомая строка отсутствует"; 
        }
     ?>
```

Comment: Советую вам обращать внимание на ваши переменные и отступы, а так же в вопросах указывать что конкретно у вас не выходит или не получилось, или скорее всего вас будут отправлять на фриланс биржи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$domains = file('domainx.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$urls = file_get_contents('urls.txt');
foreach($domains as $domain){
    if(strripos($urls, $domain) === false){
        file_put_contents('no-url.txt', $domain."\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }else{
        file_put_contents('good.txt', $domain."\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
```

Вместо комментариев, лучше откройте справочник и почитайте для чего функции и какие у них параметры.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, разобрался с функциями. А так же добавил в код регулярное выражение, теперь всё начало работать так как я хотел.

Comment: @Artem ну в вашем вопросе не было никакой информации о том что вы хотите ссылки достать а не домен. И тут благодорят отмечая ответ верным)

Comment: ну да в вопросе этого не было, я не искал окончательного решения, а хотел разобраться и скрипт закончить самостоятельно, здесь ведь люди собираются для обучения, а не задания радовать ) так же искал, что-то вроде лайка что бы вас отблагодарить, но не заметил галку. К стати как вам решение с регуляркой жизнеспособно? Или вы как профи сделали бы по другому?

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо большое за помощь, разобрался с функциями. А так же добавил в код регулярное выражение, теперь всё работает так как я хотел. Код получился такой:

```
$domains = file('domainx.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$urls = file_get_contents('urls.txt');
foreach($domains as $domain){
    if(strripos($urls, $domain) === false){
        file_put_contents('no-url.txt', $domain."\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }else{
        preg_match("/http.*{$domain}.*/", $urls, $out);
        file_put_contents('good.txt', implode("", $out), FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
```